# is there is any way to disable firebase account from code in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an application which is going to be active for first 30 days and after that the user should get automatically log out from application itself (as user's account will be deactivated), or is there is any workaround for the same because I can disable accounts from Firebase Console but that doesn't affect any user if they remains logged In.

Mainly I wanted this for Android Studio, I can do the required method through Firebase Database itself but just wanted to know if there is any alternate method available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to disable a Firebase Authentication user account, that's not possible from within web or mobile application code.  You can instead write backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK.

You can [disable the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) by updating the user and setting the disabled flag to true.  Or you can [delete the account entirely](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) if you are done with it.